# Return the value of a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

Is there a way that we can return the value from a promise? I have this async/await function meant to retrieve the token from another async/await function getToken() but it only returns a promise string to me. However, it does return the intended value in console log. What would be the best workaround for me to access the value itself and not a promise string like in the picture below?

```
const retToken = async(): Promise<any> => {
  const value = await getToken();
  console.log('value: ', value);
  return value;
}

console.log('retToken: ', retToken());
```

[image: console log results]

Comment: async functions __always__ return a promise. If you need the value, await it.

Comment: It does but the solution doesn't seem to work in my case. Refer to my reply for Nicholas D below

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to await the asynchronous function.

```js
console.log('retToken: ', await retToken());
```

Remember that asynchronous functions have to be awaited in order for them not to return a pending promise.

Comment: Everytime i added await before the call it throws this error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` and this warning from react native `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`